# Function from tuple - Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

a simple problem for ones who are good with Haskell!
Why if I write:

```
let a b = (5,6)
```

I obtain a function:

```
a :: p -> (a, b)
```

Furthermore, b is not instantiated. I tried to understand it in vain.
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer that goes into more detail about why Haskell comes up with the specific result it does:

Okay, let’s break it down. In Haskell, numeric constants can have more than one possible type, so `5` could be `Int`, `Integer`, `Word`, etc., and `(5,6)` might have type `(Int, Integer)`, `(Int, Int)` or something else.  So GHC arbitrarily denotes its type as `(a,b)` and will wait and see if you use the result later in a context that will let it deduce the type.  If not, it will default to `(Integer, Integer)`.

It so happens that GHC assigned the same lowercase letters for the unknown types that you used as identifiers on the left side of the equals sign, but they’re unrelated uses of the same names.  You can change `a b =` to `f _ = (5,6)` if that makes it clearer what Haskell is seeing when it takes you literally.

Your declaration `a b` is a function named `a` with one argument, `b`.  This parameter is unused, so GHC cannot deduce a type for it unless you call it, and it designates that as `p`.

So you declared a function that takes a `p` and returns a pair of numbers of unknown types `a` and `b`: `p -> (a,b)`.

As Sivio Mayolo beat me to saying, if you want to bind variables `a` and `b`, you can write `(a,b) = (5,6)`.

#### P.S.:

HTNW suggests I talk a little more about what values the types of the numbers can have.  [*The Haskell 2010 Report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1) says, “An integer literal represents the application of the function `fromInteger` to the appropriate value of type `Integer`.”

So, the constant `5` is equivalent to `(fromInteger (5::Integer))`.

Where’s `fromInteger` defined?  As part of the typeclass `Num`.  It has type `fromInteger  :: (Num a) => Integer -> a`.  That is, every `instance` of typeclass `Num` (including `Int`, `Double`, and so on) has its own polymorphic version of `fromInteger` defined for it that will convert an `Integer` to that type of value.

If the compiler can deduce the type of the constant, either because you provided a type annotation or because you use it in an expression that requires a specific type, it will then know which version of `fromInteger` to call to get a constant of that type.  (In fact, it will surely optimize away the call at compile time and just use the result at runtime.)  If you leave it completely up to the compiler, GHC will pick `Integer` and give you a warning.

If you try to bind `x = 5` and then use `x` as any kind of `Num`, it will work—but if you try to use it as two *different* types, the compiler won’t be able to resolve it.  So, if you need to use `x` as an `Int` in one line, and then you want to pass it as a `Double` later, you’d want to write the conversion to `Double` as `(fromIntegral x)`.  That way, `x` is an `Int` all the time and everyone’s happy.

An example of a conversion that’s possible, but not allowed by the type system: Unlike in C, trying to use a numeric literal as a `Char` will not work, as `Char` is not an instance of `Num`.  It is, however, an `Enum`, so you can use `fromEnum` and `toEnum` to convert between `Char` and `Int`.

So, if you try this in GHCI, you get:

```
Prelude> 7 :: Char

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘7’
    • In the expression: 7 :: Char
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 7 :: Char
```

`Char` is not an instance of `Num`, so there is no version of `fromInteger` that converts to `Char`.

```
Prelude> toEnum 7 :: Char
'\a'
```

This is effectively `toEnum (fromInteger 7) :: Char`.  Every `Enum` has a `toEnum` function that converts from `Int` to that type of `Enum`.  The `:: Char` at the end tells GHCI that the `Enum` to convert to is `Char`, so GHCI can deduce that it should convert 7 from `Integer` to `Int` to `Char`. Haskell borrowed from C the `'\a'` escape code for ASCII/Unicode codepoint 7.  (For *alert*, and if you typed control-G on a terminal, it used to beep at you.  It might still work in your Linux console, or at least make the window flash.)

Comment: You may want to mention that numeric literals can't have *any* type, but that they're actually `forall a. Num a => a`, and maybe explain how `fromInteger` makes this work.

Comment: It’s a topic a Haskell programmer definitely will want to get to, at some point, but maybe a little too far off on a tangent for this question? That’s very true, and why I said “more than one type,” rather than any type.

Comment: I'd say that it's important to understand how numbers are polymorphic. You've explained how the types work out, but you haven't said what actually happens to the values, and I think it's within the purview of the question. Up to you.

Comment: Okay, I added a discussion at the end, because you requested it. Kind of ambivalent about putting that here, in response to a newbie question about how to write a pair.

Answer (score 8):

```
let a b = (5, 6)
```

You are defining a function called `a`, which takes one argument, called `b`. This function ignores its argument and returns `(5, 6)`. I assume you want `a` and `b` to be bound, respectively, to `5` and `6`, in which case you want the following syntax.

```
let (a, b) = (5, 6)
```